# JTextField.setText() does not work in method as an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtextfield, settext

new Java programmer here so I might have a basic question here. I am making an array of JTextFields. I want to use setText outside of the class in a public method but it does not work. However, I am able to use setText in the class (not in a method). I am not sure why. Here is some code as a SSCCE to show what I am experiencing.
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

```
public class testSetText extends JFrame 
{
    private JPanel          panel;
    private JTextField[]    arrayField;
    private JTextField      singleField;

    public testSetText()
    {
        // Specify an action for close button
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Make a panel
        panel = new JPanel();

        // Make array of JTextField components
        JTextField[] arrayField = new JTextField[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            arrayField[i] = new JTextField(10);
            arrayField[i].setEditable(false);
            arrayField[i].setText("<>!");
            panel.add(arrayField[i]);
        }

        // Make just one JTextField component
        singleField = new JTextField(10);
        singleField.setText("Works here");
        panel.add(singleField);

        // Add to panel to frame
        add(panel);

        // Pack the contents of the window and display it
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        // This will work!
        arrayField[0].setText("Array index in class");

        // This won't? Why?
        setInMethodWithArray();

        // Is this a problem with JTextField itself? Let me try a single element
        setInMethodWithSingleElement(); 

        // Hmmm so an element in an array of JTextFields can be addressed with setText in a class but not 
        // in a method in same class with same statement. But a single JTextField can be used in a method
        // by that same class. Why do arrays behave so differently?

        // EDIT: So I misunderstood, it does not work with a non array as well either!!
    }

    public void setInMethodWithArray()
    {
        arrayField[1].setText("This text will never show up");
    }

    public void setInMethodWithSingleElement()
    {
        //singleField.setText("Works here as non-array"); <--- before edit
        singleField.setText("nevermind, it does not work here either");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new testSetText();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should declare `arrayField[]` in class area so array Field is accessible from  `setInMethodWithArray()` method.

```
JTextField[] arrayField = new JTextField[2]; //class area
```

in constructor initial it

```
 arrayField[i]= new JTextField(10);
 arrayField[i].setEditable(false);
```

---

**yes this is work**

```
arrayField[0].setText("Array index in class");
```

because arrayField in the constructor scope ..and you are accessing  arrayField Within constructor .so it works..

**This won't? Why?**

```
setInMethodWithArray();
```

because method `setInMethodWithArray()`  can't access `arrayField[]` because it's not in method scope or in class scope.that's because you have declare it in the constructor so after constructor code block execute `arrayField` doesn't exist .it's reference lost because it's `local variable` ..

```
public void setInMethodWithArray()
{
    arrayField[1].setText("This text will never show up");
}
```

now set  can access arratField[] so now your code will work

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class testSetText extends JFrame 
{
    private JPanel          panel;
    private JTextField      singleField;
    // Make array of JTextField components
    private JTextField[] arrayField = new JTextField[2];

    public testSetText()
    {
        // Specify an action for close button
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Make a panel
        panel = new JPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            arrayField[i] = new JTextField(10);
            arrayField[i].setEditable(false);
            arrayField[i].setText("<>!");
            panel.add(arrayField[i]);
        }

        // Make just one JTextField component
        singleField = new JTextField(10);
        singleField.setText("Works here");
        panel.add(singleField);

        // Add to panel to frame
        add(panel);

        // Pack the contents of the window and display it
        pack();
        setVisible(true);

        // This will work!
        arrayField[0].setText("Array index in class");

        // This won't? Why?
        setInMethodWithArray();

        // Is this a problem with JTextField itself? Let me try a single element
        setInMethodWithArray(); 

        // Hmmm so an element in an array of JTextFields can be addressed with setText in a class but not 
        // in a method in same class with same statement. But a single JTextField can be used in a method
        // by that same class. Why do arrays behave so differently?
    }

    public void setInMethodWithArray()
    {
        arrayField[1].setText("This text will never show up");
    }

    public void setInMethodWithSingleElement()
    {
        singleField.setText("Works here as non-array");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new testSetText();
    }
}
```

output>>

[image]

Comment: Is the code you provided supposed to work? I cannot get it to compile. I am still having trouble understanding to make it global. I tried some more searching and I am getting the conclusion that Java does not have global variables. Also, I remember using setText in another program I wrote but it was outside the class's constructor. Instead it was in an ActionLister under ActionPerformed. That worked fine so I am having trouble understanding the difference if it is called in a method inside the class.

Comment: @xxgiuzeppexx check it now .i just update..if you get error notify me

Comment: @xxgiuzeppexx you can call settext from any where but the text field should in the scope .

Comment: Thank you! I understand now. Now my actual program works great.